# Does the least common multiple of finite abelian groups exist?

Tags: abelian-groups, lattice-orders, least-common-multiple

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite abelian groups. A *common multiple* of $A$ and $B$ is a triple $(C,c_A,c_B)$ where $C$ is a finite abelian group and $c_A:\ A\ \hookrightarrow\ C$ and $c_B:\ B\ \hookrightarrow\ C$ are embeddings. My question is:

> Does there exist a *least* common multiple of $A$ and $B$?

Here I mean *least* in the sense that if $(T,t_A,t_B)$ is another common multiple of $A$ and $B$, then there exists a group homomorphism $f:\ C\ \rightarrow\ T$ such that $t_A=f\circ c_A$ and $t_B=f\circ c_B$.

**EDIT:** I tried a few things. The most promising seems writing $A\cong\bigoplus(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{a_q}$ where $q$ ranges over all prime powers, and the same for $B$. Then I thought maybe $C=\bigoplus_q(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{c_q}$ might work, where
$$c_{p^k}:=\max\{\sum_{i\geq k}a_{p^i},\sum_{i\geq k}b_{p^i}\}-\sum_{i>k}c_{p^i}.$$
But I am unable to prove it. Note that these definitions make sense because $a_{p^i}=b_{p^i}=0$ for $i$ sufficiently large because $A$ and $B$ are finite.

**EDIT:** As the comments made clear to me, it turns out that I mean *least* in a different sense. What I want is that if $(T,t_A,t_B)$ is another common multiple of $A$ and $B$, then there exists an embedding $C\ \hookrightarrow\ T$.

Comment: I would try using the decomposition $$
A=(\mathbb{Z}/a_1)\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/a_2)\oplus\cdots\oplus(\mathbb{Z}/a_k)
$$where $a_j\mid a_{j+1}$ and trying to get relationships between the quotients.

Comment: @DietrichBurde If $A=B\neq0$ for example, then $C=A\oplus B$ doesn't work, as the result should be $C=A=B$. For some of my thoughts on the problem, see the edit in the question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr A similar decomposition lead me to a 'conjecture' as to what $C$ might be, but things become a mess. See my edit in the question. I was hoping there would be a less messy approach.

Comment: Why do you think you should get $C = A = B$ if they are equal? That choice would not always give you a map $f$ as you want.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You are right. I should reconsider what it is that I want $C$ to be.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write  $A\cong \bigoplus_{j\in \mathbb{N}}  (\Bbb{Z}/a_j\Bbb{Z})$  and $B\cong \bigoplus_{j\in \mathbb{N}} (\Bbb{Z}/b_j\Bbb{Z})$ where $a_{j+1} \mid a_{j}$ and $b_{j+1}\mid b_{j}$.

This is basically the structure theorem for finite abelian groups, just indexed the other way around, of course almost all $a_j,b_j$ will be $1$.

Then consider $\bigoplus_{j\in \mathbb{N}}(\Bbb{Z}/ \operatorname{lcm} (a_j,b_j)\Bbb{Z})$.

Comment: This does not match the current definition. But I will boldly claim that this ought to be the answer to a corrected definition. :-)

Comment: Isn't the definition given just that of the coproduct of abelian groups? Or should the map that exists go in the other direction for that?

Comment: The way it is stated now, it is. But I'll add a corrected definition in a minute.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I feel the maps were somewhat of a distraction. The intended relation to me seemed to have been just "is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of"